# What use are Great Prophet points if you already have a religion?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

There are few features in Civ6 giving you Great Prophet points - Exodus of the Evangelists (in Rise & Fall), Holy Site Prayers and probably more.

Are these points of any use if you already have a religion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great Prophet points are strictly for getting a great prophet (just like great scientist points are strictly for getting a great scientist). Being that you can only get one Great Prophet in a game, this means that **great prophet points have no use once you've founded a religion or received a great prophet**.

Holy site prayers do give faith so it's not entirely worthless. And it's pretty much the same logic for Exodus of the Evangelists dedication.

Comment: Fairly certain the tree closes too. If you create a religion or after all prophets are obtained, the spot under great people goes empty.